# Update a row with data from another row in the same table based on a similar field

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I am using wordpress and I want to copy data from a custom field to another custom field.

Here is a visually representation of the table:

```
    post_id    meta_key    meta_value
    7          shortcode   example text 
    7          video_url   
    20         shortcode   sample text 
    20         video_url
```

I want to copy the meta_value of the shortcode to the meta_value of the video_url if their post_id matches

This is what I have so far but I am getting syntax error:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta
SET
    meta_value = newdata.meta_value
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        post_id,
        meta_value
    FROM wp_postmeta
    WHERE
        meta_key = 'shortcode'
    ) newdata
WHERE
    meta_key = "video_url" 
AND
    post_id = newdata.post_id
```

This is the error that I am getting:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that         
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near     
'FROM
(
SELECT
    post_id,
    meta_value
FROM wp_postme' at line 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use join when updating data

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta old
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta new ON old.post_id = new.post_id
SET old.meta_value = new.meta_value
WHERE old.meta_key = 'video_url' AND new.meta_key = 'shortcode';
```